# Arduino collecting both analog and GPS signals

Tags: arduino, gps

Is it possible to collect analog data and GPS with a frequency of about 200Hz? I know the GPS operates at 1, 5 or 10Hz but the analog data could be faster.

Comment: No matter what the analogue sampling frequency is, your GPS won't give more than 1, 5 or 10Hz. _It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague and incomplete and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form._

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is:  No.  You cannot collect GPS position data faster than what the GPS spits out.

The long answer:  *IF* you were designing your own GPS satellite receiver then maybe you could figure out how to do it.  But it is safe to assume that if you are asking this question in the first place then you are a long way from being able to design your own GPS receiver.  That's not an insult!  Making your own GPS receiver from scratch is hard.  Very hard.  We can't all be experts in everything.

The "correct" way to do what you want is to combine several different types of sensors.  There are several kinds of inertial navigation units (INU) that contain accelerometers and gyroscopes and can be used to tell you where you are without receiving satellite signals.  The problem with INU's is that they are inaccurate over long-ish time spans.  They can be very accurate over short time spans.  GPS's, on the other hand, are accurate over very long time-spans, and not as accurate over short time-spans.  When you combine the data from both an INU and a GPS you can get something that is accurate over short and long time-spans-- and you can get position data faster than 1, 5, or 10 Hz.

There is a whole field of study for integrating different types of sensor data into one coherent dataset.  Honestly, I'm not that familiar with it other than to say you should google "Kalman Filter".